# Shapeless. Modify tagged type

Tags: scala, shapeless, phantom-types

For instance I have two tagged types:

```
trait Created
type CreatedDttm = LocalDateTime @@ Created
type CreatedTs = Timestamp @@ Created
```

This types are used to deal with models. The first one is for common model, and the second one is for `db` entity.

```
final case class Entity(created: CreatedDttm)   // Common model
final case class EntityRow(created: CreatedTs)  // DB model
```

I have a converter somewhere in my sources:

```
def toModel(e: EntityRow) = Entity(e.created.toLocalDateTime)   // Does not compile
```

This convertion does not compile, cause `e.created.toLocalDateTime` returns `LocalDateTime`, but `Entity` needs `LocalDateTime` tagged by `Created`.

So I have to change my conversion to `tag[Created](e.created.toLocalDateTime)` to make this code compile. It works, but, imho, it looks a kind of ugly.

`Timestamp` was tagged by `Created`, and a new `LocalDateTime` must be also tagged by the same `Created`.

Is there any way to modify tagged type without need to retag a new modified value?

Comment: Standard way is retagging. You can cast but tagging is actually casting.

Answer (score 0):

Afraid not.  The best I think you can do it minimize your pain.  I would use an implicit class with a method like `toCreatedDttm`.  Something like this:

```
implicit class LocalDateTimeOps(value: LocalDateTime) {
  def toCreatedDttm: CreatedDttm = tag[Created][LocalDateTime](value)
}
```

Then you can change your line to:

```
def toModel(e: EntityRow) = Entity(e.created.toLocalDateTime.toCreatedDttm)
```

Or perhaps you can have the implicit class operate directly on the `Timestamp` like this:

```
implicit class TimestampOps(value: Timestamp) {
  def toCreatedDttm: CreatedDttm = tag[Created][LocalDateTime](value.toLocalDateTime)
}
```

Then the line could be:

```
def toModel(e: EntityRow) = Entity(e.created.toCreatedDttm)
```